# Django: Display text for multi select option in template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

So, when you use a positivesmallint field for a multiple choice question `opti= models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=OPTION1_CHOICES, default=4)`, you can display the text by doing the following:

```
OPTION1_CHOICES=(
(1, ("a")),
(2, ("b")),
(3, ("c")),
(4, ("d")),
```

)

```
{{ object.get_option1_display }}
```

However, when you have a multiselect field `option2 = MultiSelectField(choices=OPTION2_CHOICES)`the following doesn't work:

```
OPTION2_CHOICES= (
( 'e','E'),
( 'f', 'F'),
( 'g','G'),
```

)

```
{% for option in object.option2 %}
    {{ get_option_display }}
{% endfor %}
```